# Find a Latitude and Longitude at anywhere in the line connecting two latitude and longitude

Tags: python

I am caught in a big problem, where i have to find the latitude and longitude between two latitude and longitude at a certain distance, but not at the center. There are a lot of codes given to find the midpoint, but there is no formula to do this at a certain other distance ratio other than the midpoint.I am making the question more clear with below explanation.

lat1,long1-----------------------------lat2,long2------------------------------lat3,lon3

we can find midpoint and longitude i.e, lat2,long2 easily.
But, if we need to find

lat1,long1------------------------------------------lat2,long2------------------------------lat3,lon3

lat2,long2, which is say l/3 from lat1,long1 and (2/3)l from lat3, long3, where l is the total distance between lat1,long1 and lat3,long3. I am not able to find any logic for my problem. Please help.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: ok , i try and do it now.

Comment: Please explain in details what are you trying to do and include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I think i have understood. To find any point `z` between `x` and `y` (for simplicity I show you in one dimension): `z = lamda * x + (1 - lambda) * y` with  `0 <= lambda <= 1`. For example, if `lambda = 0.5`, you get the midpoint.

Comment: Anyway my answer is valid for points on a plane. I think you are working on the surface of a sphere, so I don't if my formula can be adapted to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for not replying quickly. Please review the question. I have devoted hours on it yesterday, but couldnot device any logic. I will be using it for less than 100 meter distance where earth can be approximated as a plane.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary Use dome's formula with lamda=0.33.

Comment: @Dome, please make your formula more clear or give me some link. I have to  deal here with real latitudes and longitudes

Comment: @chepner , Please suggest, if i put x as lat1 and y=lat3, and lambda=0.33, will i get the lat2?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python provides a `complex` type which can be used for working with two-dimensional points as well. The point you want is simply a weighted average of the two end points:

```
def interpolate(p1, p2, r):
    """Find a point on the line between p1 and p2.

    0 <= r <= 1

    If d is the distance between p1 and p2, then
    p3 = interpolate(p1, p2, r) is a point on the line
    between p1 and p2 such that the distance from p1 to p3
    is r * d.
    """
    return p1 * r + p2 * (1-r)


lat1 = ...
long1 = ...
lat2 = ...
long2 = ...

p1 = complex(lat1, long1)
p2 = complex(lat2, long2)

# Some examples...
p3 = interpolate(p1, p2, 0.33)  # lat3 == p3.real, long3 == p3.imag
p4 = interpolate(p1, p2, 0.67)
p5 = interpolate(p1, p2, 0.5)
```

---

This assumes that the points are close enough together that you can assume the surface of the earth between the points is approximated by a plane.

For a closer approximation, use [spherical linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), which will require first compute the angle between the two points.

Comment: Sir you are the BEST. This question was no way easy. Thank you very much for this great help.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary it's the same answer I gave you in my comment.

Comment: @Dome Thank you very much. Your answer was the BEST. I am highly grateful to you for your help.